# Sorting & Grouping in a Repeater

Tags: asp.net, .net-datasourcecontrol

In ASP.NET Can we achieve both grouping and sorting in a repeater control.
If possible please suggest me the way of doing it or links ..
I have to implement that in my application

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean visual grouping, the way I have done this sort of thing in the past is to add an ItemDataBound event to the repeater which checks the previous item using `MyRepeater.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex-1]`. If I've determined that a new group has started (i.e., if the previous item started with a different letter than the current item, and I am sorting alphabetically and grouping by letter) then I inject the appropriate HTML markup into a Literal control in the ItemTemplate to create the visual groupings.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you use the [ListView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) instead of a repeater? This has built in support for [sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.sorting(v=VS.100).aspx) and [a kind of grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.grouptemplate(v=VS.100).aspx) whilst still offering the layout flexibility you get with a Repeater.